# Hidden boxes remain hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page takes about a second for the html to load. There are several hidden divs that are set to display:none initially and then accessed by jquery toggle during normal use. However, when the page is loading, those hidden divs flash for about half a second. If the page is hard-refreshed and it takes bouat 3-4 seconds to load, then those divs are displayed for about a second or two. I'm wondering if there's any way to prevent this. I'd rather not have them flash for second if kind of looks bad. A simplified html of the page is this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>      
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />       
    <title>Site - Home</title>      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />              
    <!--JQuery-->       
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>              
    <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/popup.min.js'></script>  
</head>     

<body>      
    <a href="#" id="new-post">New Post</a>

    <!--Popup container-->
    <div id="new-post-box" class="popup" style="width:500px;">      
        blah            
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">/*popup function*/</script>              
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if that code is necessary, but can that div that display blah be prevented from appearing on the page load. Again it's set to display:none initially but I guess the css loads a little later than the html

Comment: Where do you do the hiding of the divs?

Comment: put the visible css code in the html itself (so it loads before the content in the div even starts to load, so it shouldn't flash)

Comment: you can try adding hidden property inline to the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the display:none property is in the css of the file and not in a document.ready() or other script.  That should alleviate the issue.

In the case above (I'm guessing you want to hide class='popup') so make the following in CSS

```
.popup{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: You're right, it was a stupid question I didn't look closely at my divs. The hidden proppety was handled with the javascript, so that's why it was loading late. Thank you